# Comparing items in a linked list

Tags: arrays, c, linked-list

I want to write a program which prints duplicate items of a linked list. The list is defined as such:

```
typedef struct node
{
    char *name;
    char *num[10];
    struct node* next;
    
}node;
```

I want to compare them based on the num array, which stores phone number strings. My issue is that each node may not necessarily have the same amount of phone numbers, some may have one, some may have 10. Can someone give me a hint as to how I would find if any nodes have even one number in common?

Comment: You need to take a step back. Your design needs to specify how to determine the count of valid phone numbers given a single node. That is your design decision. Some examples: store an extra field for the count or terminate the array with a `NULL` entry.

Comment: Once you have specified how the valid count is indicated it becomes a standard search problem. You should do research on search algorithms. The brute force approach would be to iterate every number in one node and compare it against every number in the other node.

Comment: Forget the linked list. Can you write a function that compares one phone number to another and returns the number of shared digits?

Comment: This question is too broad. First solve how to find a given phone number in a phone number string.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple approach:

1. Define a `struct { char* name; char* num; };`.
2. `malloc()` an array with capacity for `10 * length(list)` of those structs.
3. Iterate over the linked list, copying every phone number with its associated name into the array.  You need to define what it means for some of the 10 phone number slots to be empty (e.g. maybe unused phone numbers are NULL).
4. Sort the array by the phone number string contents (use `qsort()` and `strcmp()`).
5. Iterate over the array, at each step remembering the last phone number you saw, and printing any numbers that match the previous entry.